# How do I share Firebase auth data across an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have an app that has 2 view controllers. One is the login/register page, and the other is the page that SHOULD change a UILabel to say the user's email, but it doesn't. I guess it's because I don't have the data from the first view controller. So how can I get the data from the first view controller?

Here's part of the code from `SecondViewController.swift`

```
if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
    self.usernameLabel.text = user.email
    print(user.email)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to grab a single event "snapshot" of the user's email from Firebase DB.  The email is stored as a dictionary entry in Firebase. So this is what's worked for me:

```
let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
FirDatabase.database().reference()child("YOUR_FIREBASE_CHILD_NODE").child(uid!).
observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

   if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
   self.usernameLabel.text = dictionary["email"] as? String
}
```